# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'HeapNode' and 'HeapNode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap, nodes, huffman-code

When I try to push a node onto heap for the huffman tree I get this error:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'HeapNode' and 'HeapNode'

```
    class HuffmanCoding:
        def __init__(self, path):
            self.path = path
            self.heap = []
            self.codes = {}
            self.reverse_mapping = {}

        def make_heap(self, frequency):
            for key in frequency:
                node = HeapNode(key, frequency[key])
                heapq.heappush(self.heap, node)
```

Node class:

```
    class HeapNode:
        def __init__(self, char, freq):
            self.char = char
            self.freq = freq
            self.left = None
            self.right = None

        def __cmp__(self, other):
            if(other == None):
                return -1
            if(not isinstance(other, HeapNode)):
                return -1
            return self.freq > other.freq
```

The error is being caused by:

```
    heapq.heappush(self.heap, node)
```

[Full code by github.com/bhrigu123](https://github.com/bhrigu123/huffman-coding/blob/master/huffman.py)

Comment: It looks like `HeapNode` doesn't support ordering (it doesn't have a `__lt__` or `__eq__`, etc methods)

Comment: I believe @mgilson is correct. You need to overload comparison operators. Also, nice name.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__

Comment: You try to call operator `<` on two heap nodes, but you never defined such a method.

Answer (score 5):

The current version of the program here works. I tested. https://github.com/bhrigu123/huffman-coding/blob/master/huffman.py

```
#Modified code here for reference
class HeapNode:
    def __init__(self, char, freq):
        self.char = char
        self.freq = freq
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    # defining comparators less_than and equals
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.freq < other.freq

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if(other == None):
            return False
        if(not isinstance(other, HeapNode)):
            return False
        return self.freq == other.freq
```

Comment: While links can be good, try to quote the most important parts, just in case the link is down or something alike.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Mangu